# Why text in div doesn't display from top

Tags: css, css-float

I'm learning CSS, there're some behaviors that I don't understand, please look at the code snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #testDiv{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      float: left;
    }
    #testDiv1{
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
    <div id="testDiv1">
      <p>
        This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.his is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.his is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know the first div will cover the sceond one, but why the text in the second div doesn't be covered? It display from the position after the first div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean why the text doesn't display from the top of the page, you can
>   see, it display under the first div.

The first div pushes the 2:nd div down, it doesn't float on top, as the property "float" might suggests.

To make the text start at top, use absolute positioning on the first div or either give the second a negative margin or a left margin (as in below sample) matching the first div's width and it will line up next to the first.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #testDiv{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      float: left;
    }
    #testDiv1{
      margin-left: 100px;           /*  added    */
      width: 100px;
      min-height: 200px;            /*  changed  */
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
    <div id="testDiv1">
      <p>
        This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.his is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.his is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I mean why the text doesn't display from the top of the page, you can see, it display under the first div.

Comment: @Allen4Tech Updated my answer again. Does it clear things out for you?

Answer (score 0):

[Floated](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) elements are out-of-flow, and thus the first element overlaps the second. However, they are special because they shrink line boxes:

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

In this case, since it's as wide as the following element, the line boxes at the top have no width, and thus the text goes below to the line boxes after the float, which have some width.

If you don't want the first element to shrink the line boxes of the second one, you should use other out-of-flow modes like [absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning):

> In the absolute positioning model, a box [...] is removed from the
>   normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings).

```css
#testDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: .8;
  position: absolute;
}
#testDiv1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv"></div>
<div id="testDiv1">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.his is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.his is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
```